# Is it possible to use v-bind:value or v-model for the object gotten from the network?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

I want for `VueApp` to use `v-model` or `v-bind:value` for the object got from the `network api`.
For example, the `Vue app` gets the object from the `api` like this

```
 {
   field1:value1, field2:value2, ......... , field100:value100
 }
```

The number of fields are large.
To use `v-model='obj.field'` , I think that the `Vue app` has to define the data as following.

```
 new Vue({
   el:"#mainapp",
   data:{
    obj:{field:''}
   }
   ...
}
```

Could I use the `v-model` for the object gotten from the `api` without definition for the field of `object` in `vue app data`?
Main reason that I need this is that the number of fields are large and I couldn't be sure that all fields are existed in the `obj`.
(like `field99` in the below example)
I think to define all fields of the object, `obj`, in `vue app data` is bad experience.

Example I want.

```
 //script
  new Vue({
    el:"#mainapp",
    data:{
      obj:{}
    },
    created(){
       this.$http.get('urltoget_object')
      .then((res)=>{
         this.obj = res.body.data;  //this returns object by data field.
      }, (err)=>{}); 

    }
    ...
  }

<input type='text' v-model= 'obj.field100' />
<input type='text' v-model= 'obj.field99.netstedfield' />
```

How could I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

set data after got data from remote api, make it responsive by using [this.$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set).

```
//script
new Vue({
  el:"#mainapp",
  data:{
    obj:{}
  },
  created(){
     this.$http.get('urltoget_object')
    .then((res)=>{
       this.obj = res.body.data;  //this returns object by data field.
       this.$set(this,'obj',res.body.data)
   }, (err)=>{}); 
  }
  ...
}

<input v-if="'field100' in obj" type='text' v-model= 'obj.field100' />
```

Comment: When the `field99` is not in `obj`, the above works?

Comment: add an if condition to check whether the property is in obj